# Composer install of ESR (Extended Security Release)?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-9, esr

How do I manage a CiviCRM ESR  (Extended Security Release) install on a Drupal 8/9 composer installation?

I've subscribed to the CiviCRM ESR service and I'm trying to install an ESR version on my Drupal 9, which manages the CiviCRM code with composer, so I don't want to download the tarball.

Answer (score 2):

After you've subscribed to the ESR service, you'll get access to a private group on the civicrm gitlab install, with the instructions here:

https://lab.civicrm.org/esr/examples

There are actually three ways to do it provided, but the recommended method (which now works with Composer 2 in spite of the warning) uses the private composer packages provided by civicrm's gitlab installation, which can be accessed by your composer magic with the use of a gitlab authentication token that you can generate if you have access to that repo.

https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/release/-/issues/8

Comment: And if you ended up here actually looking for the download option, then that's here: https://lab.civicrm.org/esr/core/-/releases